# delete records from 2 tables after testing to see if they are duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, duplicates, duplicate-data

Editing someone else's SQL Server design here:

I have been tasked with removing duplicate rows from a database.

I have 2 tables: `table1` and `table2`.

- `table1` has columns `T1ID, and T1NAME`
- `table2` has columns `T2ID, DATA1, DATA2, DATA3`
- Tables join on `T1ID = T2ID`

If several rows have the same `T1NAME, DATA1, DATA2`, **AND** `DATA3`, I need to remove all but one of them from both tables.

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: whups...will edit question: MS SQL Server

Comment: For duplicate records, do they have different IDs (T1ID, T2ID). Understand from the question that T1ID = T2ID, but if two rows (A and B) have the same name and data, does T1ID (for A) = T1ID (for B)?

Comment: So if you have "duplicates" - which one of the rows do you want to keep? What to use to decide this? Or do you want to keep just an arbitrary row from n duplicates?

Comment: Which one to keep is unimportant: the records were added during earlier testing (they used copies of real entries to test) and are highly redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess t1id in table1 and t2id in table2 is primary key for corrosponding tables.

if so the you can use following approach -

1) as you want to delete from both the tables, you need to store the t1id (or t2id) into one **temp table** so that you can use the values for deleting second table

2) for extracting the desired t1id/t2id you need to group the joined table with T1name, Data1, Data2, Data3 and select the record where you are getting multiple records.

3) Exclude only one t1id from duplicate records found for delete.

so for this you can use some commands like shown below -

```
CREATE TABLE test_table
 as (SELECT T1id
      FROM Table1, Table2
     WHERE T1name, Data1, Data2,
     Data3 IN (SELECT T1name, Data1, Data2, Data3
                       FROM (SELECT T1name, Data1, Data2, Data3, COUNT(*)
                               FROM Table1, Table2
                              WHERE T1id = T2id
                              GROUP BY T1name, Data1, Data2, Data3
                             HAVING COUNT(*) > 1))
       AND T1id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(T1id)
                          FROM Table1, Table2
                         WHERE T1id = T2id
                         GROUP BY T1name, Data1, Data2, Data3));

DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE T1id IN (SELECT T1id FROM Test_Table);

DELETE FROM Table2 WHERE T2id IN (SELECT T1id FROM Test_Table);

COMMIT;

Drop TABLE Test_Table;
```

Comment: GOT IT. I am going to give this a try...I think I was trying too hard to make it all one command and your method just sidesteps that entire issue. Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 0):

Untested but try something like this

```
    ;with deleteThis
as
(
select   t1.id
        ,t2.data1
        ,t2.data2
        ,t2.data3
        ,row_number() over(partition by t1.id,t2.data1,t2.data2,t2.data3 order by t1.id) as rn
from table1 as t1
inner join table2 as t2
on t2.id = t1.id
)
delete from deleteThis
where rn > 1
```

Comment: Wouldn't that delete **all** rows where duplicates exist? The OP said he needs to keep **one row** if there are multiple ....

Comment: Wouldn't this only delete content from table1?

Comment: (thanks for the feedback wootscoot: im jr. learner level here)